# Vim change colour for typedef

Tags: vim

I am using typedef in a C file. I want to change the colour of those words that define a type to the colour used for data types. Can I do that?

Comment: Is this really on topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a plugin [TagHighlight](http://www.cgtk.co.uk/vim-scripts/taghighlight) for vim to highlight classes, typedefs etc supporting different languages, which you can try.

> TagHighlight is a plugin that highlights names of classes, variables,
>   types etc in source code in Vim. This makes it quicker and easier to
>   spot errors in your code. By using exuberant ctags and parsing the
>   output, the typedefs, #defines, enumerated names etc are all clearly
>   highlighted in different colours.